# Atualizar tabela dinamica por ultimo. VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu criei uma planilha conectada ao meu ERP via ODBC e tenho algumas tabelas dinamicas na mesma planilha.

Estou tentando criar uma macro que atualiza todos os dados, mas usando `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` o comando esta atualizando primeiro as tabelas dinâmicas e depois as conexões ODBC.

No caso eu preciso que as tabelas dinâmicas sejam atualizadas por último, pois os dados estão interligados.

Eu tentei essa macro mas sem sucesso:

```
Sub RefreshAll_AgingStock()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    Worksheets("PivotTable2").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224384/3846228), vemos que uma possível solução p/ o seu problema pode ser a seguinte:

Em `Propriedades de Conexões`, desmarque a opção `"Enable Background Refresh"` ou `"Habilitar Atualização em Segundo Plano"`. 
Isso fará com que a conexão somente seja atualizada quando especificado pelo usuário, não em segundo plano enquanto os outros processos estão rodando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a opção `"Habilitar Atualização em Segundo Plano"` **desabilitada**, sua macro deve aguardar até que os seus dados externos estejam atualizados, antes de pular p/ a próxima linha de código.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").Refresh
Sheets("SHEET_NAME").PivotTables("PIVOT_TABLE_NAME").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Você também pode desligar a opção de atualização em segundo plano através do seguinte comando:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
```

**Implementando no seu código:**

```
Sub RefreshAll_AgingStock()

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 'or ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").Refresh
    Worksheets("SHEET_NAME").PivotTables("PIVOT_TABLE_NAME").PivotCache.Refresh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Já [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836346/3846228), o usuário disse que atualizou o código acima para desabilitar a atualização em segundo plano de todas as conexões existentes na pasta de trabalho, e após isso, atualizar os dados existentes nelas.

```
Sub Refresh()

    Dim conn As Variant

    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        conn.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    Next conn

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```